# How to use localStorage in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to set a variable in asp.net page using `localStorage` and retrieve it on another page?

What could I use to read this variable after setting it?

Comment: You use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) from Javascript; the choice of server-side framework is irrelevant.

Comment: thanks Richard Deeming